# multiple notification by AlarmManager and receiver Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, notifications

i set two different alarms that should make 2 notifications

8:34:0 pm create notification 1 with title and msg..

8:34:10 pm create notification 2 with title and msg...

the problem is they both appear together at 8:34:00 pm
 (at the first alarm time (both))!!!

what i did:-

1- i made a broadcast class  with notification manager to build notification

2- main activity created alarmManager and calendar instance to set time for alarm.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Creating alarm method(requestcode,hours,min,seconds)
            setAlarmo(1,20,34,0);
            setAlarmo(2,20,34,10);

        }

    // the Alarm Method
        public void setAlarmo(int reqcode, int hour,int minute,int second){


            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,second);

            long timeinMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AlertRec.class);
            intent.putExtra("reqcode",reqcode);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),reqcode,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(alarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,timeinMillis,pendingIntent);

        }

    }
```

@

```
// AlertClass receiver extending broadcastReceiver
    public class AlertRec extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive( final Context context, Intent intent) {

// Creating receiveAlarm method(requestCode,Context,intent,title,text for notification)

//receiving first Alarm from MainActivity.Class 
         recAlarmo(1, context,intent,"title 1","im msg 1");


//receiving Second Alarm from MainActivity.Class     
         recAlarmo(2,context,intent,"title 2","im msg 2");
    }


    // receiving Alarms Method and Creating Notifications

    public void recAlarmo(int reqcode , Context context,Intent intent,String title,String msg){


     intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);

     NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(),reqcode,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
     builder.setContentTitle(title);
     builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.star_on);
     builder.setContentText(msg);
     builder.setAutoCancel(true);
     builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
     builder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);

     NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

     nm.notify(reqcode,builder.build());

    }
    }
```

@

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM"></uses-permission>


        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <receiver android:name=".AlertRec"></receiver>
        </application>
```

Comment: Seems like your hr , min n sec is same both the times you are setting alarm .  setAlarmo(1,20,05,0);
        setAlarmo(2,20,45,0);

Comment: no the first one is  8:34:00 pm  and the second one after it with 10 seconds 8:34:10 pm

Comment: The code example is too large to allow easy analysis. You need to reduce it to the smallest possible way to reproduce the problem. When readers have to scroll both horizontally and vertically to see all of the code, they're less likely to answer.

Comment: ;( i did my best reducing it srry

Answer (score 1):

```
    i solved it !
    ------------------------------

    in MainActivity 

    1-create a method that takes int number
    and inside the method make a pending intent and within the intent of the pending intent
     pass the int number as intent.putExtra("id",number);

public void Method(int id ,int hour , int minute, int seconds){

 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,second);

 Intent alertIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlertRec.class);
            alertIntent.putExtra("id",id);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),id,alertIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

}

    ----------------------------------------------------
    2- at the Receiver class 


    //override the OnReceive method

    onReceive(Context context,Intent intent ){

     int Checker =intent.getExtras.getInt("id");

             if(Checker == 1 ) {

                 // do anything you want for the intent of the pending intent at MainActivity that have int id  = 1;
            //your method here

             }else if(Checker == 2) {

                 // do anything you want for the intent of the pending intent at MainActivity that have int id  = 2;
            // your method here

             }else{
    }

    }
```